# 500 Internal Server Error trying to fetch data with Django Rest Framework through Javascript

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, fetch

I'm trying to get the post data from the backend using fetch. However i am getting a 500 server error when trying to fetch the data. I have tried using *.serialize()* in the backend to pass the data. as well as trying to return the **jsonResponse** by serializing the query object which would give me this error: **Object of type User is not JSON serializable**. I tried it by sending an object and without an object. Any suggestions?

code models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT, default='',null=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,null=True,related_name="posts")
    
    def serialize(self):
            return {
            "id": self.id,
            "user": self.user,
            "likes": [user for user in self.likes.all()],
            "message": self.message,
            "date": self.date.strftime("%b %d %Y")
        }
```

code urls.py

```
path("post/<int:id>",views.post, name="post")
```

code views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def post(request,id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == "GET":
        return JsonResponse({"post":post.serialize()})
```

code script.js (**post.getAttribute('name')** is the post id)

```
posts.forEach(post => {
fetch(`post/${post.getAttribute('name')}`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

)}

Comment: If you're using django rest framework, you should be using a [serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/). Much easier than writing custom serialization for each model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying User model instance to convert JSON. Just change `"user": self.user to "user": self.user.email` or whatever you want

```
def serialize(self):
        return {
        "id": self.id,
        "user": self.user.email,
        "likes": [user.id for user in self.likes.all()],
        "message": self.message,
        "date": self.date.strftime("%b %d %Y")
    }
```

Comment: nope, still getting the error

Comment: You have to change likes as well, I've edited my answer

Comment: After 9 hours, i finally found the solution. Lol, I will surely save this in my notes. 
Thank you so much.